# test: too many arguments in bash script

Tags: bash

I have an expression like following in a bash script:

`if test $year % 4 -eq 0`

but it's throwing a warning `line 5: test: too many arguments`

what is the problem here? how I can fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `test` builtin doesn't do arithmetic; it doesn't understand the `%` notation.

If you really want to use `test`, then you could write:

```
if test $((year % 4)) -eq 0
```

(using [arithmetic expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arithmetic-Expansion); the `$((year % 4))` bit gets replaced with the relevant value before `test` is invoked); but I think it's simpler and clearer to write:

```
if ((year % 4 == 0))
```

(using an [arithmetic expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs) instead).